# Clang static analyzer on Windows

Tags: visual-studio-2008, clang, clang-static-analyzer

Does anybody have any success running clang static analyzer on Windows?

I have successfully built llvm and clang (using VS 2008). Running scan-build results in the following error:

```
The getpwuid function is unimplemented at scan-build line 35.
```

Some research shows that **getpwuid** is not supported on Windows platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the call to ...

```
my $UserName =  HtmlEscape('unknown')
```

scan-build is a perl script, so will need some handy fixes to execute scan build on windows.. these are

-> point those variables to look at the absolute physical path

```
my $ClangSB, my $Clang; $Dir = "/tmp"; my $Cmd ; and my $CmdCXX
```

please remember, that my $Cmd ; and my $CmdCXX is path of ccc-analyzer and c++-analyzer ... which are also perl scripts, so please place a perl -w in front of absolute path string..

and also disable the variable check right after declaration...

! -x $blaBla is problematic on windows...

beside you will also need these changes

--> CHANGE

```
open(PIPE, "-|", $Clang, "-cc1", "-help") or
```

to

```
open(PIPE, "-|", "$Clang"." -cc1"." -help") or
```

surprise, scan-build is working on windows.. :)